# Figure environment undefined

Tags: undefined

I am trying to use `\begin{figure} \end{figure}` however I get the error that it is undefined. 
I am using `\usepackage{float, graphicx}` in the beginning in the doc.

It is important to mention that i am using a custom document class called `moderncv.cls` which I found online.

I already tried to use `\RequirePackage{float,graphicx}` in the moderncv.cls. However this is also not working.

Do you have any suggestion on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Most likely floating `figure`s are useless in `moderncv` and as such not provided by the class. You don't need a `figure` environment, just use `\includegraphics`

Comment: The same is true for `table`, but actually, I did not check that within `moderncv`

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics See, no  need for a figure environment.

Comment: I want to place my image very specifically on the top right. On the same line as the chapter and i think I would need figure for that?

Comment: @user3410232: No, `figure` is not necessary at all. If you want to have a caption (unlikely for a CV, I assume), you can use `\includegraphics` and `\captionof{figure}{Foo caption}` (with `caption` package, for example)

Comment: I do not want a caption that is right.
Is there any possibility to place the image with coordinates in an "absolute" style?